# Echo variables in terminal after running compiled simulink model

Tags: c, simulink

I'm building a real time simulink application to interface with a robot. Is there a way to output variables to the terminal when I run the executable (C code generated by simulink coder and then built)?

I ultimately want to see the output of the axes a joystick I have connected.

As it stands now, when I run the application, the prompt goes blank and the robot's speaker turns on (as intended). Before I start controlling its joints with a controller I want to see actual output of the analog sticks in the terminal so I know that it actually works.

It's just a way for debugging.

So my question is: How do I echo out variables into the terminal using simulink coder?